# I want to know what if a color repeats, and if so change a drawable

Tags: c#, performance, object-oriented, xamarin

So I made this code:

```
 private List<eventAndColor> GetEventosToPopulateCalendar()
    {
        // A List with only the days that have events
        List<Eventos> CalEvents = eventDao.Select(FromEventos.DistinctDate);

        // A List of a struct with Date + color of event
        List<eventAndColor> events = new List<eventAndColor>();

        // If List isn't null
        if (CalEvents != null)
        {
            // Iterate through the days that have events
            foreach (var calEvent in CalEvents)
            {
                var eventsInDay = eventDao.Select(FromEventos.WhereDay, calEvent.DataDocumento); // A List with all events on that day                 
                bool hasDifColor = false; // A bool to flag if it encounters a different color

                // Iterate through all the events on the day
                foreach (var day in eventsInDay)
                    if (day.Cor != calEvent.Cor) // Only set hasDifColor to True if it founds a different color
                    {
                        hasDifColor = true;
                        break; // Break loop
                    }

                if (hasDifColor)
                    events.Add(new eventAndColor(calEvent.DataDocumento, MULTIPLE_EVENTS)); // Add a tag of multiple event colors
                else
                    events.Add(new eventAndColor(calEvent.DataDocumento, calEvent.Cor)); // Add a tag of an event color
            }
            return events;
        }
        else
            return events = new List<eventAndColor>(); // Empty list
    }
```

It's objective is to check the events of a group of dates, and see if in each day  if the events inside it have different colors, if it does I tell that there are multiple color events in that specific day. the problem here is that I don't like this code, it looks too messy, I wanted to know if theres anyway to optimise it.

(I'm talking about the loops, but I welcome any other criticism towards my code)

The "Eventos" Class and the Struc are here if needed:

**Struct**

```
public struct eventAndColor
    {
        public DateTime eventDate;
        public string colorHex;

        public eventAndColor(DateTime date, string color)
        {
            eventDate = date;
            colorHex  = color;
        }
    }
```

**Eventos**

```
public class Eventos : Evento, IEnumerable
{
    public List<Eventos> eventos = new List<Eventos>(); 

    public void Add(Eventos evento) { eventos.Add(evento); }

    public Eventos Get(int position) { return eventos[position]; }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { return eventos.GetEnumerator(); }

    public Eventos() { }
}

public class Evento : Java.Lang.Object
{
    #region Table Columns Names

    public const string COLUMN_Id                     = "ID";
    public const string COLUMN_DataHoraRegistoSistema = "Data Hora Registo Sistema";
    public const string COLUMN_NoDocumento            = "No Documento";
    public const string COLUMN_NoColaborador          = "No Colaborador";
    public const string COLUMN_Descricao              = "Descricao";
    public const string COLUMN_Local                  = "Local";
    public const string COLUMN_DataDocumento          = "Data Documento";
    public const string COLUMN_HoraDe                 = "Hora De";
    public const string COLUMN_HoraA                  = "Hora A";
    public const string COLUMN_TipoTarefa             = "Tipo Tarefa";
    public const string COLUMN_Equipa                 = "Equipa";
    public const string COLUMN_NoDocumentoLigacao     = "No Documento Ligacao";
    public const string COLUMN_IdTarefaMov            = "Id Tarefa Mov";
    public const string COLUMN_Recorrente             = "Recorrente";
    public const string COLUMN_IdAtividade            = "Id Atividade";
    public const string COLUMN_NoEntidade             = "No Entidade";
    public const string COLUMN_NoCliente              = "No Cliente";
    public const string COLUMN_NoContrato             = "No Contrato";
    public const string COLUMN_NoLinhaContrato        = "No Linha Contrato";
    public const string COLUMN_NoProduto              = "No Produto";
    public const string COLUMN_NoInvestimento         = "No Investimento";
    public const string COLUMN_SegProcesso            = "Seg Processo";
    public const string COLUMN_Eliminado              = "Eliminado";
    public const string COLUMN_Concluido              = "Concluido";
    public const string COLUMN_Cor                    = "Cor";

    #endregion

    #region Table Fields

    [Column(COLUMN_Id), PrimaryKey, NotNull, Unique, AutoIncrement]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    [Column(COLUMN_DataHoraRegistoSistema)]
    public DateTime DataHoraRegistoSistema { get; set; }
    [Column(COLUMN_NoDocumento)]
    public string NoDocumento              { get; set; } = "";
    [Column(COLUMN_NoColaborador)]                           
    public string NoColaborador            { get; set; } = "";
    [Column(COLUMN_Descricao)]                                     
    public string Descricao                { get; set; } = "";
    [Column(COLUMN_Local)]                      
    public string Local                    { get; set; } = "";
    [Column(COLUMN_DataDocumento)]                           
    public DateTime DataDocumento          { get; set; }
    [Column(COLUMN_HoraDe)]                    
    public DateTime HoraDe                 { get; set; }
    [Column(COLUMN_HoraA)]                     
    public DateTime HoraA                  { get; set; }
    [Column(COLUMN_TipoTarefa)]                
    public int TipoTarefa                  { get; set; } = 0;
    [Column(COLUMN_Equipa)]                     
    public string Equipa                   { get; set; } = "";
    [Column(COLUMN_NoDocumentoLigacao)]       
    public string NoDocumentoLigacao       { get; set; } = "";
    [Column(COLUMN_IdTarefaMov)]              
    public int IdTarefaMov                 { get; set; } = 0;
    [Column(COLUMN_Recorrente)]                                       
    public bool Recorrente                 { get; set; } = false;
    [Column(COLUMN_IdAtividade)]                             
    public int IdAtividade                 { get; set; } = 0;
    [Column(COLUMN_NoEntidade)]                              
    public string NoEntidade               { get; set; } = "";
    [Column(COLUMN_NoCliente)]                               
    public string NoCliente                { get; set; } = "";
    [Column(COLUMN_NoContrato)]                              
    public string NoContrato               { get; set; } = "";
    [Column(COLUMN_NoLinhaContrato)]                                 
    public string NoLinhaContrato          { get; set; } = "";
    [Column(COLUMN_NoProduto)]                               
    public string NoProduto                { get; set; } = "";
    [Column(COLUMN_NoInvestimento)]                          
    public string NoInvestimento           { get; set; } = "";
    [Column(COLUMN_SegProcesso)]                             
    public string SegProcesso              { get; set; } = "";
    [Column(COLUMN_Eliminado)]                                
    public bool Eliminado                  { get; set; } = false;
    [Column(COLUMN_Concluido)]                                
    public bool Concluido                  { get; set; } = false;
    [Column(COLUMN_Cor)]
    public string Cor                      { get; set; } = "#1869BF";

    #endregion        
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a guard condition regarding `CalEvents` being `null` you can save one level of indentation like so

```
private List<eventAndColor> GetEventosToPopulateCalendar()
{
    // A List with only the days that have events
    List<Eventos> calEvents = eventDao.Select(FromEventos.DistinctDate);

    if (calEvents == null || calEvents.Count == 0)
    {
        return new List<eventAndColor>();
    }

    // A List of a struct with Date + color of event
    List<eventAndColor> events = new List<eventAndColor>();
```

Maybe you have noticed that the former `CalEvents` are now named `calEvents` because method-level variables should be named using `camlCase` casing. You can read more about it in the [.NET Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx).

The inner loop can be replaced with some `Linq`-magic like so

```
if (eventsInDay.Any(day => day.Cor != calEvent.Cor))
{
    events.Add(new eventAndColor(calEvent.DataDocumento, MULTIPLE_EVENTS)); // Add a tag of multiple event colors
}
else
{
    events.Add(new eventAndColor(calEvent.DataDocumento, calEvent.Cor)); // Add a tag of an event color
}
```

or maybe better like so

```
string desiredColor = calEvent.Cor
if (eventsInDay.Any(day => day.Cor != calEvent.Cor))
{
    desiredColor = MULTIPLE_EVENTS; // Add a tag of multiple event colors
}
events.Add(new eventAndColor(calEvent.DataDocumento, desiredColor)); // Add a tag of an event color
```

Putting all together would result in

```
private List<eventAndColor> GetEventosToPopulateCalendar()
{
    // A List with only the days that have events
    List<Eventos> calEvents = eventDao.Select(FromEventos.DistinctDate);

    if (calEvents == null || calEvents.Count == 0)
    {
        return new List<eventAndColor>();
    }

    // A List of a struct with Date + color of event
    List<eventAndColor> events = new List<eventAndColor>();
    foreach (var calEvent in calEvents)
    {
        var eventsInDay = eventDao.Select(FromEventos.WhereDay, calEvent.DataDocumento); // A List with all events on that day                 

        string desiredColor = calEvent.Cor
        if (eventsInDay.Any(day => day.Cor != calEvent.Cor))
        {
            desiredColor = MULTIPLE_EVENTS; // Add a tag of multiple event colors
        }
        events.Add(new eventAndColor(calEvent.DataDocumento, desiredColor)); // Add a tag of an event color
    }
    return events;
}
```

Some more words regarding your code and coding-style:

- Because most developers are coding using english as a language to name things you should do this as well. In this way if some other (non native speaker of your language) developer should maintain your code it will be much easier.
- Because most developers expect a specific style, which mostly is based on the .NET Naming Guidelines you should stick to that style as well. E.g `eventAndColor` should be named using `PascalCase` casing.
- Don't omit braces `{}` althought they might be optional.

Answer (score 2):

I can only add to Heslacher:

1) Your comments are almost all redundant in that they explain what is obvious. Use comments to explain the not so obvious - why the code does what it does for instance.

2) Brackets:

> ```
>             foreach (var day in eventsInDay)
>                 if (day.Cor != calEvent.Cor) // Only set hasDifColor to True if it founds a different color
>                 {
>                     hasDifColor = true;
>                     break; // Break loop
>                 }
> ```

this is possible but should be avoided. For a small loop like this, it is though easy to understand, but the larger the loops are, the more difficult it becomes to read. So always use curly brackets:

```
foreach (var day in eventsInDay)
{
  if (day.Cor != calEvent.Cor) // Only set hasDifColor to True if it founds a different color
  {
    hasDifColor = true;
    break; // Break loop
  }
}
```

---

Heslachers suggestion could be taken some steps further:

1)

```
  foreach (var calEvent in CalEvents)
  {
    var eventsInDay = eventDao.Select(FromEventos.WhereDay, calEvent.DataDocumento);
    var cor = eventsInDay.Any(eid => eid.Cor != calEvent.Cor) ? MULTIPLE_EVENTS : calEvent.Cor;
    events.Add(new eventAndColor(calEvent.DataDocumento, cor));
  }
```

2)

or you could go all in on LINQ:

```
  var groups = from calEvent in CalEvents
               group calEvent by
               eventDao
               .Select(FromEventos.WhereDay, calEvent.DataDocumento)
               .Any(day => day.Cor != calEvent.Cor) ? MULTIPLE_EVENTS : calEvent.Cor;

  events.AddRange(groups.SelectMany(group => group.Select(ce => new eventAndColor(ce.DataDocumento, group.Key))));
```

---

A detail to consider:

You compare two strings in this way:

```
day.Cor != calEvent.Cor
```

are you sure, that they always have the same case?
Consider using:

```
string.Equals(day.Cor, calEvent.Cor, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

or one of the other `IgnoreCase` `StringComparison`s if case doesn't matter.